# Is there the way to avoid opacity is inherited?

Tags: cocoa-touch, titanium

Is there the way to avoid opacity is inherited?

This is my source code in titanium.
Tt means that one `imageview` is added to parent `imageview`.

I would like to make 'shadow' transparent and `arrow` is not transparent and on it.

But Both `ImageView`(`shadow` and `arrow`) are transparent even I set `opacity=1` on `Arrow`.

This is specific in titanium or common in objective-c??

**index.xml**

```
<ImageView id="ShadowR" onClick="clickShadowR" >
<ImageView id="RightArrow" />
</ImageView>
```

**index.tss**

```
"#RightArrow": {
    image:"/img/SwitchRightArrow.png",height:'80%',opacity=1
},
"#ShadowR": {
    opacity:0.5,
    backgroundColor: 'ddd'

},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, objective-C is a programming language. You are speaking here about Cocoa/Cocoa Touch which are UI Frameworks.

As far as I know, this is not even specific to Cocoa, this is valid in any UI framework I know.

Consider an example from real world - I have a car. The car has a door. I make the car invisible (I am Batman), why should the door stay visible?

If you put an image view `B` into another image view `A`, you are making it a part of it. If you move `A`, both views will move. If you make `A` transparent, both will be made transparent because `B` is a part of `A`.

The workaround is simple - create a container view `C` and put both `A` and `B` there without `B` being a part of `A`.

Comment: Its cool explanation,and your workaround way is useful and it works perfectly.thanks